# installed mediterraneandark theme, but doesn't look like example

Tags: themes

I have installed a theme in Ubuntu 12.10, and the preview image looks like

[image: this].

However, Nautilus file manager looks the same, it's just the window manager top part (title, close, minimise maximise) which has changed.

Am I missing a step?

To clarify: The colours have changed, but the layout and buttons remain the same. It looks like

[image: this].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first image is either Nautilus 3.6+, Nemo, or Athena File Manager. The second image is Nautilus 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install **Nautilus 3.6**. It is not included in Ubuntu 12.10 repositories, so run following commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

and then:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Now you just have to kill all Nautilus processes:

```
$ killall nautilus
```

and upgrade your software:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You should have Nautilus 3.6 now.

Comment: there is a typo 'kilall' should be 'killall' (but for some reason an edit needs to be 6 characters long)